# How to submit form from another component

Tags: javascript, angular, dom

Hello i have to integrate some vanilla js methods that access the DOM with Angular and i was wondering if there are alternatives ?

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <form id="computerCreateForm" method="post" action="@(Startup.config.ServerUrl+URL)">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Computer Id</label>

            <input class="form-control" type="text" value="" name="ID" id="id" />
            <label>Username</label>  
            <input class="form-control" type="text" value="" name="Username" id="name" />
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
submit: function (id) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            var form = document.getElementById(id);
            form.onerror = () => {
                reject("could not post");
            }
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            var action = form.getAttribute('action');
            var method = form.getAttribute('method');
            xhr.open(method, action);

            xhr.onload = function () {
                if (xhr.status == 200) {
                    resolve(xhr.response);
                }
                else if (xhr.status != 200) {
                    reject("Failed to submit form with status" + xhr.status);
                }
            }
            var data = new FormData(form);
            xhr.send(data);
        });
    },
```

**Component**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ROUTES } from 'src/app/Constants/Routes';


@Component({
  selector: 'computer-create-form',
  templateUrl: './computer-create-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./computer-create-form.component.css']
})
export class ComputerCreateFormComponent implements OnInit {
  protected users:1;
  protected readonly URL:string=ROUTES.ADD_COMPUTER;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

As you  can see i need to perform a submit from outside the current component.

**Some other component**

```
someButtonClick():void{
     //window.submit("computerCreateForm");
  }
```

On a button click would call the `submit()` method.Do i need vanilla js to be able to do that ?

Comment: Does outside component is the parent component of the component which has form?

Comment: The parent is a modal.The parent of the modal calls the `submit`.So we have  `Root { Modal { Form } }` .

Comment: Could you provide your parent component and it html, and also child component which contain form and it html?